# How to change the state of a specific value in an array with condition

Tags: reactjs

I want to change a value inside an array with a certain condition, I tried several ways but I could not, the last one I tried was this:

```
addResponse (e) {
        const { current_component_id, responses, current_question_id 
        } = this.state;

        this.setState(prevState => {
            const responses = prevState.responses.map((item, j) => {
                if (item.question_id === current_question_id) {
                    return item.answer_component = current_component_id
                        }
                    })
                })
    };
```

This is my state:

```
type State = {
  current_question: number,
  current_component_id: number,
  current_question_id: number,

  responses: Array<{
      enrollment_id: number,
      evaluation_id: number,
      question_id: number,
      answer_component: number,
      user_id: number,
  }>,
};
```

I want to find the responses.question_id equal to current_question_id and change the responses.answer_component = current_component_id

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
prevState.responses.map((item, j) => {
  if (item.question_id === current_question_id) {
    return {...item, answer_component: current_component_id };
  }
  return item;
}
```

I'm using the `===` operator instead of `=`, the first one is a comparison operator while the other is the assignment.

To return correctly the object, I'm using the spread object notation

Comment: does not work, it enters 'if', but return does not work